# using IR receiver with raspberry pi 3

Tags: lirc

I am trying to read Infrared using lirc library but I have had no success I followed this instruction http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Useemulate-remotes-with-Arduino-and-Raspber/ and made all the changes mentioned by it did almost 2 hours of research but when I run `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`
I get this error :

```
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc0
Cannot initiate device /dev/lirc0
```

Comment: What happens when you test your setup with: "mode2 -d /dev/lirc0" like it says in step 9 of the instructables web page?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I neede to run the command as root, ie.
`sudo mode2 -d /dev/lirc0`.  Not sure why this isn't mentioned in any of the instructions that I could find.  Hopefully this helps anyone else who comes across this question.